# Applescript create and rename file from other files

Tags: applescript, filenames, rename, automator

In order to import .MOV files (h.264) to Final Cut Pro I need a correspoding .THM file with the same filename as the .MOV. Is it possible to do this with an AppleScript or Automator? Here is what I want to do:

1. Create a copy of a "TEMPLATE.THM" file that already exists on my HD
2. Rename the "TEMPLATE.THM" file using the .MOV filename
3. Do this to a folder of .MOV files to create a .THM file for every .MOV file both with the same filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**G'day**

This might not be the quickest way — but I see you're still waiting for an answer — so here's something to get you started. Select all your MOV files in the finder and run this in script editor.

```
set theTemplate to "Macintosh HD:Users:[user name]:[folder:location]:TEMPLATE.THM"

tell application "Finder"
  set theFiles to selection
  repeat with thisFile in theFiles
    set thisName to name of thisFile
    set theFolder to container of thisFile
    set newFile to duplicate theTemplate to theFolder

    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to "."
    set thisName to text item 1 of thisName
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to ""

    set newName to (thisName & ".THM")
    set name of newFile to newName
  end repeat
end tell
```

The easiest way to get the path to the template is to select it in the finder and run this :

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to selection as string
end tell
```

That will put the path in your results window — just copy it into the first line of the script above.

Hope that helps

**m.**